# ¿Liberar espacio de una macbook pro?

Tags: macos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál es la mejor forma de liberar espacio en mi disco duro, tengo mucho espacio ocupado en la categoría Other y no se a que archivos corresponde y como limpiar lo que ya no me sirve ? ¿Qué me aconsejan ?

Comment: Esta pregunta no está relacionada a desarrollo. En mi opinión, no está relacionada a los temas del sitio. Por favor lee [help/on-topic]

Comment: Que la formatees nuevamente, previo respaldo de tu información.

Answer (score 0):

Esta herramienta te puede servir y es gratis https://diskwave.barthe.ph/. Te ayuda a determinar qué es lo que te está ocupando espacio en disco con más detalle.

Esta es otra herramienta que también está buena http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/

Recordá vaciar la papelera de reciclaje que es algo que también consume espacio en disco.